# Not In Condition Not working in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I cleaned it up a bit, so the problem is why searchmodel returns room with id=30 when i say not to
searchModel Code

```
public function search($params)
{
   $ids = [];
   $ids[]=30;
    $query = room::find();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    $this->load($params);
    if (!$this->validate()) {

     }
 $query->andFilterWhere([
        'price' => $this->price,
        'category_id' => $this->category_id,
        'id' => $this->id,
        'ci_id'=>$this->ci_id;

    ]);
    $query->andFilterWhere(['not in','id',$ids]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Controller Action here is the controller action i dont think there is anything weird there just posting in case there is something wrong.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new roomSearch();
    //$user = Yii::$app->user->identity;

    if ($searchModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
else{

  //

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);


    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
}
```

and the view code that shows the rooms is the code below:

```
  <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['timeout' => 30000, 'clientOptions' => ['container' => 'pjax-container']]); 
?>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'action' => ['index'],
'method' => 'get','options' => ['data-pjax' => true ],]); ?>
 <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'category_id')->dropdownList(MtCat::getHierarchy(false, [], false, false),['onchange'=>'this.form.submit()','prompt' => 'Όλες οι κατηγορίες']); ?>
 <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'ci_id')->dropdownList(City::getList(),['onchange'=>'this.form.submit()','prompt' => 'Όλες οι περιοχές']); ?>

   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</br>


<?=

ListView::widget([

    'layout' => "{pager}\n{summary}\n<div class='all-items'>{items}</div>\n{pager}",

    //'layout' => "{pager}\n<div class='all-items'>{items}</div>\n{pager}",

    'summary' => sprintf('<div class="summary"><b>%s</b> αποτελέσματα δωματίων</div>', $dataProvider->totalCount),

    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

     'showOnEmpty' => false,


    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],

    'itemView' => '_img', /* function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) { return Html::a(Html::encode($model->id), ['view', 'id' => $model->id]); }, */

    'pager' => [

        'maxButtonCount' => ceil($dataProvider->totalCount / $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize),

    ],

]);

?>
 <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: What does `$query->where('0=1');` mean?

Comment: dont know been there from previous dev :P

Comment: its just something that returns nothing :P it says in comment above it

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your `if` statement after `$query->where('0=1');`, because it's only filtering when data in your model is not valid by `$model->validate()`. It should look like this:

```
public function search($params)
{
   $ids = [];
   $ids[]=30;
   $query = room::find();
   $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
   ]);
   $this->load($params);
   if (!$this->validate()) {

   } // here you need close if condition
   $query->andFilterWhere([
        'price' => $this->price,
        'category_id' => $this->category_id,
        'id' => $this->id,
        'ci_id'=>$this->ci_id;

   ]);

   $query->andFilterWhere(['not in','id',$ids]);

   return $dataProvider;
}
```

Comment: i changed it and it still return the room with id=30

Comment: I m new here where should i paste it ?

Comment: i updated the code and cleaned up the comments and those i dont use :D

Comment: Okay, so now, if you removed `$query->where('0=1');` you can delete this `if` statement aswell... :P Anyway, try to add this: `var_dump($query->createCommand()->rawSql);die;` right before `return` statement. Place here result.

Comment: sorry but how can i see the output of vardump if i place it in the model ? im a total rookie in frameworks xD

Comment: If you run your action where you use this model and `search()` method it will show on your screen ;)

Comment: i totally mess up on purpose the search model and i get no error and search working the same i dont get it i will post the whole form in view maybe i am doing something else wrong

Comment: Are you sure youre using `search()` method from `roomSearch` class? After adding this `var_dump(...);die;` you should see only SQL query on your screen.

Comment: i messed up guys sorry for your time really. The problem from the beggining was the paths i had paths to the wrong model,controller... :/ how can i delete this thread?

Comment: There should be a delete option under your question.

Comment: i cant do it cause you invested time on the thread xD thanks tho i learned some tricks on how to identify the source of error :)

Comment: Okay, have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks mate, you too and sorry !

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that you select only

> room_id

that's why it does not see

> id

You can change first few lines of your code like that.

```
$ids = [];
$ids[] = 30;
$results = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('select id,room_id from y2gall_reservations')->queryAll();
$query = room::find();
```

Comment: Room_id is a foreign key om reservations table and id is that key in rooms table

Answer (score 0):

Your model search function should as :

```
 public function search($params)
 {
   $ids = [];
   $ids[]=30;
   $query = room::find();
   $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => $query,
   ]);
   $this->load($params);
   if (!$this->validate()) {

   }
   $query->andFilterWhere([
     'price' => $this->price,
     'category_id' => $this->category_id,

     'ci_id'=>$this->ci_id;

   ]);
   $query->andFilterWhere(['not in','id',$ids]);
   return $dataProvider;
 }
```

Remove id param from first andFilterWhere function.